# Errors in my program to read IP addresses from server log files

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to C# and have a question.

My server has log files with lines like

> 2015-05-14 20:56:50 72.167.255.87 GET
>   /images/email/site_05_12_2015/email-contactus-button.png
>   - 80 - 50.48.46.50 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+Microsoft+Outlook+15.0.4711;+Microsoft+Outlook+15.0.4711;+ms-office;+MSOffice+15)
>   304 0 0 46

and my program is intended to collect the unique IP addresses that request a certain asset. In the above line I would extract `"50.48.46.50"` if the program was searching for `"email-contactus-button.png"`.

Here it is:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic; 


class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // args[0] = expression to search for, e.g. "cloudrealized-email-top-banner"
        try
        {
            string [] logs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            Console.WriteLine("{0} log files found", logs.Length);
            HashSet<string> ipList;
            string ipreg = "^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$";
            foreach (string thislog in logs)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(thislog))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Checking log file {0} for expression '{1}' ...\n", thislog, args[0]);
                    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    if (line.Contains(args[0]))
                    {
                        Match thisip = Regex.Match(line,ipreg);
                        thisip = thisip.NextMatch();
                        if (thisip.ToString() != args[1]) ipList.Add(thisip);

                    }
                    //for (Match m = Regex.Match(line,regx); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch()) ++count;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nRESULT:\n\nThe asset {0} was requested {1} times.", args[0], ipList.Count());
            Console.WriteLine("Unique IPs:");
            foreach (string s in ipList) Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error occured: ");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

The first compiler warning I'm getting is on the line

```
string ipreg = "^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$";
```

because it thinks I'm trying to escape the `.` character. How can I fix that?

The other two warnings are on the methods I call on `iplist`. They are not recognized, and I can't figure out why. The documentation I was looking at for `HashSet` is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: Write "\\." instead of "\.". You must escape the backslash in the string literal, so that the regex compiler sees the literal backslash (which escapes the dot from its special meaning in regex syntax). Even better, use verbatim strings for regex literals (verbatim strings have an at-sign before the opening quote. @"\." will evaluate to the string consisting of a backslash and a dot.

Comment: Also: Unique IP addresses are not very reliable counter for independent site hits. Users behind a NAT will appear as one IP; One user will have a distinct IP once they reconnect with their ISP ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic C# example of a regex expression to pull out that IP address.  This is assuming that all of your log files will be structured the same way.

```
string strRegex = @"(?<=-\s)([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"2015-05-14 20:56:50 72.167.255.87 GET /images/email/site_05_12_2015/email-contactus-button.png - 80 - 50.48.46.50 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+Microsoft+Outlook+15.0.4711;+Microsoft+Outlook+15.0.4711;+ms-office;+MSOffice+15) 304 0 0 46";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    if (myMatch.Success)
    {
    // Add your code here
    }
}
```